# Apache redirect directory to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, indexing

I'm trying to redirect a simple folder to /folder/index.php.

My URL looks like this : site.com/folder and I want site.com/folder/index.php.
Throught de web I only found the reverse way but I do want to see my index.php so that I can later use links like site.com/folder/index.php#344

My .htaccess located in /folder/ looks like this :

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

And of course it doesn't work.
Maybe is apache ignoring my file ? Maybe some others .htaccess are interfering ? I have no idea since I'm new to apache...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You could just skip this mod_rewrite stuff and use mod_dir:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

With that in the htaccess file in `/folder`, going to `http://site.com/folder` you will get served the contents of `index.php`.